# Pandas DF : how to replace '-' by '_' with separators (; CSV format)

Tags: python, regex, pandas, csv

I need help with regular expressions and regex functions!!! I have a CSV file separeted by ';' and need to replace - by _. The data looks like this :

```
79             80;0;RueSaint_Hilaire;Locale;15-25;1;1             
80              81;0;RueSaint_Hilaire;Locale;5-10;5;5             
81                   82;0;RueTaillon;Locale;10-15;1;1             
82                   83;0;RueTanguay;Locale;10-15;2;2             
83                   84;0;RueTanguay;Locale;15-25;2;2             
84                    85;0;RueTanguay;Locale;5-10;3;3
```

and I would need to replace, for instance, 15-25 by 15_25.

So far I've tried this :

```
df.replace('-','_', inplace=True)
```

or this :

```
df_obj = df.select_dtypes(['object'])
df[df_obj.columns] = df_obj.apply(lambda x: x.str.strip())
df.replace('-','_', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

without any success. Any regex or replace wizard out here could shed some light on this little problem?

Thank you so much!

Comment: `RueSaint-Hilaire` should change to `RueSaint_Hilaire`? Also do you want those fields read into separate columns, or is one big string what you're after?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The names are already corrected from a previous database. I need the 15-25, 5-10, 10-15 (and so on...) to be changed to 15_25,5_10,10_15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest implementation I can think of:

```
with open(<PATH TO FILE>, 'r') as fileIn:
    data = fileIn.read()
    print("\nOriginal data: \n", data)
    data = data.replace('-', '_')
    print("Modified data: \n", data)
```

This gives out:

```
Original data:
80,0,RueSaint-Hilaire,Locale,15-25,1,1
81,0,RueSaint-Hilaire,Locale,10-May,5,5

Modified data:
80,0,RueSaint_Hilaire,Locale,15_25,1,1
81,0,RueSaint_Hilaire,Locale,10_May,5,5
```

Answer (score 3):

By default the `regex=False`. So, with your existing code use regex replace by `regex=True` and `inplace=True`. SEE [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html#pandas-dataframe-replace)

```
df.replace('-', '_',regex=True, inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Comment: I was simply missing the regex=True argument. Thanks for pointing that out !

Comment: Yes, That's why I've added the **replace** manual for you also. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I would go for:

```
df['Col'] = df['Col'].str.replace('-', '_')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good faq on pandas: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/pandas/info

Apply a lambda to the dataframe as follows:

`df['foo'] = df['foo'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('_', '-'))`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to change specifically your `-` between numbers, go for:

```
import re

regex = r"(\d+)-(\d+)"

test_str = ("79             80;0;RueSaint_Hilaire;Locale;15-25;1;1         \n"
    "80              81;0;RueSaint_Hilaire;Locale;5-10;5;5         \n"
    "81                   82;0;RueTaillon;Locale;10-15;1;1         \n"
    "82                   83;0;RueTanguay;Locale;10-15;2;2         \n"
    "83                   84;0;RueTanguay;Locale;15-25;2;2         \n"
    "84                    85;0;RueTanguay;Locale;5-10;3;3  ")

subst = "$1_$2"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)
```

You can check the regex here: https://regex101.com/r/DGrm7V/1